# select option to Change text color on selected option not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code below , which changes the color of the selected option works fine for all browsers, but this doesnt seem to work on IE9.  Not sure what iam missing, really appreciate ur help

```
        select {
  color: #1771b7 !important;  // color of the selected option
 }

select option {
   color:#555 !important; // color of all the other options
}   


<div class="styled-select">
   <select id="selectedBusinessType" name="selectedBusinessType" >
      <option value="default">Select</option>
                <option value="auto">Auto</option>
                <option value="demo">Demo</option>
                <option value="fg" selected="selected">Demo fgsdf</option>
                <option value="st">ST</option>
                <option value="publish-wf">publish w/f</option>
                <option value="test">test</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I think this is what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/049Lj4LL/2/
I changed the colors so I could see the change The pseudo-class `option:checked` is what ya need

```
 select {
      color: green;  /* color of the selected option*/
     }

    option {
       color:red; /* color of all the other options*/
    }   
    option:checked { color: green; }
```

Comment: I have posted the working code here https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/b9ytz4yL/  but it still isnt working

Comment: It is working look at my fiddle with your extra css code  but make sure you expand the window inside the JS fiddle first https://jsfiddle.net/b9ytz4yL/1/